# error downloading $metadata from webservice

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services, service-reference

I am trying to add web reference when adding web reference url in windows application it shows error like this. how do i solve it?

There was an error downloading 'http://www.example.com/BackEndWebService/LoginWebService.asmx/$metadata'.

### The request failed with the error message:

$metadata Web Service method name is not valid.

Comment: Are you adding it as a web reference, or a service reference? Web references are deprecated.

Comment: I am adding it as Service Reference which displays dailogue box , in advanced button i clicked Add Web Reference and enter the url

Comment: Can you open it in a browser? There might be an issue with the web service. See http://blog.consejoinc.com/2012/12/interesting-cause-for-exception.html

Comment: yes,i open it in a bowser and it  is working well..

Comment: Just had the same issue, I finally figured out that selecting the service on VS and going to properties shows the url, just changed it and it worked.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had the same issue the other day when tried to update the web reference and managed to fix it by adding ?WSDL at the end. That should work.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! In my case was a external java web service and I replaced the dot by a question mark: https://webservice.web/webservicename.wsdl --> https://webservice.web/webservicename?wsdl and it worked!

Comment: Is this behavior explained/documented somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got this error for adding a Hashtable as a parameter and it failed because it's not supported:

`The type system.collections.hashtable is not supported because it implements IDictionary`

IDictionary is not serializable, so in my case I switched to a simple array